# php count users post

Tags: count, posts

i am having some problem counting users posts from db, it's kind of confusing because all the id's/row are in the same table.

the table:

categories | id1 | id2 | title | msg | userid

---

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE authorid='".$id2."'";
$rows = mysql_query($query);
echo $rows['id2'] ;
?>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation. `mysql_query` doesn't return rows. And the way you access it, it's more like you expect a single row there. Besides, you may want to connect to the database (depends on your php.ini, though, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM topics WHERE authorid='".$id2."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['count'] ;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your problem ? With this code, if you want to count user posts for ths authorid '2' then put $id2 = 2 and it will return 2 no ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*)AS count FROM topics WHERE authorid='".$id2."'";
```

Then after you fetch the row (this will depend on what database library you're using), you can do something like:

```
echo $rows['count'];
```